# How can I secure my web service, username/password or token?

Tags: web-services, security

I am now developing web service, but i  want person who are authenticated have the right to use the web service. Now I have two methods, one is use username and password in every service, the other is first use username and password to login and get token, then visit other services just by token. Now I want to know which is better? Suppose I use https, it is secure to pass username and password. But my mentor told usually we use token. So can any compare these two methods detaily from security,performance or any other aspects?Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SOAP, you can implement soap header authentication.
Or Basic in http header

Comment: I'm not using SOAP.It seems that authenticate username/password every time i need to connect database, that costs too much.Also i want to make service RESTful, it seems a confict to SOAP?

Comment: I'm not very aware about rest authentication methods but you can do like this :
 - Client auth on server (username / passwd)
 - Server generate key and store it in memory
 - each client call are done with key and server just validate key before executing something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply~ I think that's the idea of token~

Answer (score 0):

Implement the system in the following way.

The User should send an Encrypted Format password and UserID in the first request.

The Password authentication logic can be unique to you but make sure that the password is not exposed in the SOAP message as plain text.

Next at your service side, implement a service handler which maintains a list of authenticated IP addresses.

Whenever a new IP address tries to contact your service, you validate its credentials and then if authenticated, you add the IP to your safe IP List.

In case the Authentication fails you reject the request.

In case of Multiple services, implement a common Service Handler for the same. and keep the IP list as a static variable.

Other than this You can look into Web Service Security:

- [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/b32511/intro_security.htm)
- [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security)

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your apply~ If use ip to implement, it will allow other applications use my service with the same ip?

Comment: Firstly i think u dont understand that only applications with your WSDL will be able to access your web service...therefore in case you have authenticated an application then only it will be able to access the Web Service. Secondly, The security is against hacking and all. That means in case some one forges a request similar to 1 launched by one of your clients..or in case u have licence system implemented. In each case password authentication works and is safe against other applications.

else you will have to apply heavier protocols

Comment: Actually i know little about WSDL.If i have two applications, one is good, the other is controlled by hacker. the good app autheticate itself and the server record my ip as safe ip, then the bad app can visit the service because of the same ip. The second you mentioned means check password everytime?Do you record anything else besides ip?

Comment: U can set parameter as per your requirement...But then the client would have to implement a similar logic at that end...u can provide library for the same as per need.

Comment: Hey Buddy...accept the answer if its correct...we gotta care about our repo too u know..

Comment: sorry,actually i want to hear more answers. If there's no other answer, i'll accept your answer~